# Tensorflow with Angular 7 : Failed to compile

Tags: angular, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use Tensorflow.js with Angular (v7), but ng build fails with error: `ERROR in ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-data/dist/tf-data.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue. I think the fix mentioned above should work, but I personally fixed it changing:

```
node: false,
```

By:

```
node: {fs: 'empty'},
```

In the line 133 (method getBrowserConfig) of the file located at *node_modules/@angular_devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js*

This bug looks like something new, as it happens to me while using tfjs 0.15.0, but didn't happen before when I was using the version 0.13.1.

Answer (score 4):

A hacky fix is adding:

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

to your `package.json`.